# How to create PHP SplStack from array

Tags: php, spl

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to create `SplStack` from an array. Sure I can write a simple function that will do that:

```
function stackFromArray(array $array): SplStack
{
    $stack = new SplStack();
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        $stack->push($item);
    }

    return $stack;
}
```

However, I don't like this approach, because I have to iterate over the array and push items one by one. Is there a way to create a stack directly from the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation doesn't suggest any method to use, nor does it specify that the constructor can be used through the SplDoublyLinkedList.

Since, really, all the SplStack is just a SplDoublyLinkedList wrapper, you could easily create a Facade to achieve this.

Create a simple interface for future extendability and testability:

```
interface SplStackFacadeInterface
{ 
    public static function fromArray(array $arr);
}
```

Extend the `SplStack` functionality for coupling.

```
class SplStackFacade extends SplStack implements SplStackFacadeInterface
{
    public static function fromArray(array $arr): SplStack
    {
        $splStack = new self();
        array_map([$splStack, 'push'], $arr);
        return $splStack;
    }
}
```

Then just use it like so:

```
$stack = SplStackFacade::fromArray([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

See it working over at [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Epj6l)

Comment: Well, your solution does basically the same as my simple function however, I agree that it has better usability. The answer give me confirmation that I didn't miss some secret part of the documentation.

Comment: I found it hard to answer without just saying, "no its not possible according to the docs" so I thought I'd shine on how I'd approach it; its ashame the `SplDoublyLinkedList` doesn't have a constructor to pass a predefined array that just simply invokes the internal `push` method like we're having to do with `array_map`.